# Is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f)$ a principal ideal ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring, if $R$ is a Dedekind domain and $I$ is a nonzero ideal, then $R/I$ is a principal ideal ring (PIR).

In particular, in the case where $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a Dedekind domain ($\alpha$ algebraic integer), and taking $I=nR$, $n\geq 1$, we get that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[X]/(\bar{f})$ is a PIR, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

This leads to the following question.

**Question.** Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer, and let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ a **monic** polynomial. Is $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[X]/(\bar{f})$ a PIR?

Clearly, CRT shows that it is enough to assume that $n$ is a prime power.

I'm happy to assume that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't think it will be necessary.

Assuming $n=p^r,r\geq 1$, I've tried to consider the canonical surjection $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[X]/(\bar{f})\to (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[X]/(\bar{f})$ without success for the moment.

Any ideas, references, proofs or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Comment: No. Take $n=p^2$, $f=X^2$, and consider the ideal $(p,X)$. However, if $r=1$ and $f$ separable mod $p$, then $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f)$ is finite over a (finite) field, so is reduced and the product of its (finitely many) localizations, so it is enough to show the PIR property for local finite reduced $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras – but then they are finite fields as well thus PIR. I think the assumption isn’t optimal when $r=1$.

Comment: Wait, when $r=1$, $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f)$ is a quotient of a PIR so is a PIR.